# Why rotating reference frames are not inertial?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotation, inertial-frames, galilean-relativity

Let's say I'm standing on the equator, and that there is no other reference point in the sky.

If the planet is rotating, then I measure my weight to be lower than if it is not.

But given that I have no reference frames to "prove" than I am rotating, why can't I just claim that my weight should be the same since I'm standing still and the universe is rotating around me?

(After all, this kind of argument *does* work for translation... so what's different about rotation?)

Comment: "*But given that I have no reference frames to "prove" than I am rotating,...*" yes, you do: see [Foucault pendulum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foucault_pendulum)

Comment: To tell that you are rotating, you dont have to have a reference point, a [Foucault pendulum](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foucault_pendulum&ved=0ahUKEwiI7piKxaTMAhXPBo4KHZ6sBGEQFggbMAA&usg=AFQjCNFc9tY3g9Sgsli8R9z9d3KVXrzliQ&sig2=X7V2jdS1qX4rvMoJczffSA) could do the job

Comment: I think that unfortunately the Foucault pendulum does not "work", ie show a rotation, at the Equator?

Comment: Yes, I was about to say that. A Foucault pendulum shows the biggest effect at the poles and zero effect at the equator. Instead I suggest you throw an object north and observe the [Coriolis force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coriolis_force).

Comment: Not only that, but it completely misses the point of my question, but unfortunately for me I can't find the words to explain it better. However, I can say that if a Foucault pendulum is your answer, then I think you haven't understood the crux of my confusion... in fact I was already familiar with the Foucault pendulum before I asked this, and it did not answer my question. I'm confused why the world behaves the way it does, not asking how it behaves.

Comment: I think the OP's confusion is similar to the "Newton's bucket", right?

Comment: @JohnRennie I don't think the question is whether you can know you are in a non-inertial frame, it's how that works in the absence of any obvious inertial reference frames: is this the Mach thing?  I forget.  However I think this is a more subtle question than the comments make it seem.

Comment: Hi Merhad. Given your clarification I think your question is a duplicate. If you disagree ping me and I'll withdraw the close vote.